# app is not installed error after change gradle version, compile version and buildToolsVersion

Tags: android

I'm trying to install my app in a android 7.1.2 and it shows: app is not installed after it is complete.
What I change is grandle from 4.0.2 to 7.0.3:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-bin.zip
```

It was Central() I change to maven:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Compile sdk was 30:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
```

I add this in manifest for android 12:

```
android:exported="false">
```

And update build tools:

```
buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
```

I try to re-install the app many times in this device and the same error occurs.

Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the previous/older apk from the device. Then install the latest build, it will install without any errors